# I want to write an algorithm for two circles intersection and touching cases . How can I do it with a quadtratic equation?

Tags: geometry, education, soddy-circles

Given that two circles with coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and radius r1 and r2 respectively . I need to find an equation , which can be used in code to to find the coordinates and the presence of touching and intersection . 
Like Ay2 +  By + C = 0 .

> Circle 1 (x - x1)2 + (y - y1)2 = R1 * R1
>   Circle 2 (x - x2)2 + (y - y2)2 = R2 * R2

Comment: You'll need to solve a nonlinear system of equations.

Comment: Can't I just get a formula for intersction points of two circles , with these give points ?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to find such a formula.